# Thing i should know before starting apache solr?

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene

What are thing that I should know before starting with Apache Solr?

I don't know anything about Solr.

I have worked only with MySQL.

What I came to know about Solr after googling is that I should know xml, Jason (REST like API), Java.

Are my assumption is true?

Please pardon me if I am wrong.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what an irony just down voting without any help :( .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to achieve.
If you want to build the search engine then yes you can migrate the data from mysql to solr using data import handler.

Here the XML, json and SQL are enough for you to go ahead.

You can call the rest APIs of solr to integrate solr with your application.

Comment: thank you i got the solution of all my question.